# Problem with logout hook in react-google-login when using typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-authentication

I have problem with onLogoutSuccess:

```
 const onLogoutSuccess = (res: any) =>{
    alert('Logout successfully');
  }

const { signOut } = useGoogleLogout({
    clientId,
    onLogoutSuccess,
    onFailure
  })
```

I get the error:

```
(property) UseGoogleLogoutProps.onLogoutSuccess?: (() => void) | undefined
Type '(res: any) => void' is not assignable to type '() => void'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(136, 12): The expected type comes from property 'onLogoutSuccess' which is declared here on type 'UseGoogleLogoutProps'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export interface GoogleLogoutProps {
  readonly clientId: string,
  readonly onLogoutSuccess?: () => void;
  readonly onFailure?: () => void;
  ....
}
```

You are getting that error because, **onLogoutSuccess** hook does not have parameters. In your case use passed in res:any.

You can just use it like this, and you won't get that error.

```
  const onLogoutSuccess = () => {
    console.log("logout success");
  }

  const onFailure = () => {
    console.log("logout failure");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue please have a look I hope it's helpful for your goal.

JS code

```
const onLogoutSuccess = () => {
    console.log('logout');
    history.push('/');
  };
  const onFailure = () => {
    console.log('logout fail');
  };
  const { signOut } = useGoogleLogout({
    clientId: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    onLogoutSuccess: onLogoutSuccess,
    onFailure: onFailure,
  });
```

Html

```
 <button onClick={signOut}>Log Out</button>
```